# Пересечение двух прямых в matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Есть две прямых построенных по двум точкам:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

a_dots = [
    [0,-1],
    [1,0]
]

b_dots = [
    [0,2],
    [4,0]
]

a_df = pd.DataFrame(a_dots, index=['x','y'])
b_df = pd.DataFrame(b_dots, index=['x','y'])

a_dft = a_df.T
b_dft = b_df.T

plt.plot(a_dft['x'], a_dft['y'], marker='o');
plt.plot(b_dft['x'], b_dft['y'], marker='o');
```

График должен отображать пересечение этих прямых, но одна до другой не дотягивает, как не добавляя лишних точек продлить линию до пересечения (отобразить пересечение прямых)?

Comment: по-моему не добавляя "лишних" точек - не получится...

Comment: @MaxU в моем случае это отрезок, а может как то можно провести прямую через две точки, что бы она именно на точках не заканчивалась а шла до конца графика?

Comment: Можно пойти от обратного: найти точку пересечения, немного продлить отрезок за эту точку, и по этим точкам нарисовать.

Comment: @insolor дело в том что нужно без лишних точек это сделать, неужели в matplotlib не предусмотрена возможность рисовать прямые через точки, и все ограничивается отрезками

Comment: [попробуйте так ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9153411/5741205)

Comment: @MaxU с англ, беда у меня ), не могли бы вы выделить от туда решение проблемы ?

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч, сейчас не могу - пишу с телефона. Там собственно только код по ссылке...

Comment: @MaxU не могу разобраться в том коде, если не затруднит напишите ответ с комментариями как будет возможность

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуемся [данным решением](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9153411/5741205):

```
def drawLine2P(x,y,xlims):
    xrange = np.arange(xlims[0],xlims[1],0.1)
    A = np.vstack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T
    k, b = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y)[0]
    plt.plot(xrange, k*xrange + b, 'k')
```

Исходные точки (в виде `Pandas.DataFrame`'s):

```
In [108]: a
Out[108]:
   x  y
0  0  1
1 -1  0

In [109]: b
Out[109]:
   x  y
0  0  4
1  2  0
```

Рисуем отрезки:

```
In [110]: plt.plot(a['x'], a['y'], marker='o')
Out[110]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xec23be0>]

In [111]: plt.plot(b['x'], b['y'], marker='o')
Out[111]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xeb05048>]
```

Получаем `ax` object:

```
In [112]: ax = plt.gca()

In [113]: ax.get_xlim()
Out[113]: (-1.1499999999999999, 2.1499999999999999)
```

"Продолжаем" отрезок:

```
In [114]: drawLine2P(a['x'], a['y'], ax.get_xlim())
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понятно, как вы хотите делать *без лишних точек*. Прямую, ограниченную чем вы хотите получить на отображении? Поиск точки перечесения это не задача для графического пакета.
В самом примитивном варианте можно использовать средства библиотеки `sympy`. Как вам и сказали в комментарии, ищем точку пересечения, добавляем ее.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import Line, Point, Segment
import numpy as np

x1, y1 = [0, 1], [-1, 0]
x2, y2 = [0, 4], [2, 0]

# объекты точек
p1, p2, p3, p4 = (Point(x1[0], y1[0]), Point(x1[1], y1[1]),
                  Point(x2[0], y2[0]), Point(x2[1], y2[1]))

# объекты прямых для установления факта пересечения
# объекты отрезков для проверки наличия точки пересечения уже на отрезке
line1, seg1 = Line(p1, p2), Segment(p1, p2)
line2, seg2 = Line(p3, p4), Segment(p3, p4)

intersect = line1.intersection(line2)

l1, = plt.plot(x1, y1, marker='o', zorder=3)
l2, = plt.plot(x2, y2, marker='o', zorder=3)

if intersect:
    pi = intersect[0]
    if not seg1.contains(pi):
        xydata = l1.get_xydata()
        xydata = np.vstack((xydata, [pi.x, pi.y]))
        plt.plot(xydata[:, 0], xydata[:, 1], '--', alpha=.5)

    if not seg2.contains(pi):
        xydata = l2.get_xydata()
        xydata = np.vstack((xydata, [pi.x, pi.y]))
        plt.plot(xydata[:, 0], xydata[:, 1], '--', alpha=.5)    
plt.show()
```

Тут, конечно, еще желательно проверять, из какой именно точки отрезка проводить эту псевдопрямую до точки пересечения.